# Can I move built package frome one machine to other?

Tags: c++, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I have a problem with working in a virtual machine of ROS Electric, which is running on Ubuntu 10.04. It does not want to compile any nodes, written in C++ code. So I wonder if I can create the nodes in some other virtual machine where there are no problems in C++ compilation and then just move it back to Electric?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206992/can-i-move-built-package-frome-one-machine-to-other?/) by [Dio Eraclea](https://answers.ros.org/users/21681/dio-eraclea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this would only work under the following circumstances (I did it once under Ubuntu 12.04 / Hydro):

- The machine you are building on uses exactly the same operating system version, and has exactly the same set of libraries (+versions) installed, including the ROS version
- Both machines use the same architecture (e.g. x86 or x64)

In those cases, you could just copy the binaries. However, in general I would recommend highly against it, and instead fix the original issue. Why can't you compile C++ code on that machine? Which error messages do you get?

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2015-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1